# Change div html content clicking on menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Got the next menu:

```
   <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
     <a href="http://www.myweb1.com" id="menu">Web1</a>
     <a href="http://www.myweb2.com" id="menu">Web2</a>
     <a href="http://www.myweb3.com" id="menu">Web3</a>
     <a href="http://www.myweb4.com" id="menu">Web4</a>
   </div>
```

And the next div container with an opened web by default:

```
<div id="main"></div>

<script>
    $("#main")
        .html('<object data="http://www.myweb1.com"/>');
</script>
```

I want to change this default main web when you click the menu option, so I'm trying something like:

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#menu", function(e) {

    /*$("#main").load("main.html");*/

    if ($("#menu").text() == "Web1"){
        $("#main").html('<object data="http://www.myweb1.com"/>');
    }
    if ($("#menu").text() == "Web2"){
        $("#main").html('<object data="http://www.myweb2.com"/>');
    }
    if ($("#menu").text() == "Web3"){
        $("#main").html('<object data="http://www.myweb3.com"/>');
    }
    if ($("#menu").text() == "Web4"){
        $("#main").html('<object data="http://www.myweb3.com"/>');
    }

    });

</script>
```

I'm new to jquery, sorry if It's an obvious question.

Comment: Keep id as unique, like _id="menu1",id="menu2",id="menu3,id="menu4""_

Comment: You can not do more than one id with the same name in the same page, so change **id="menu"** by **calss="menu"** in HTML and change **#menu** by **".menu"** in JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` must be unique in the DOM Tree, so you have to change the `id="menu"` for `class="menu"` as well as you javascript code

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
     <a href="http://www.myweb1.com" class="menu">Web1</a>
     <a href="http://www.myweb2.com" class="menu">Web2</a>
     <a href="http://www.myweb3.com" class="menu">Web3</a>
     <a href="http://www.myweb4.com" class="menu">Web4</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).on("click", ".menu", function(e) {
    /*$("#main").load("main.html");*/

    e.preventDefault()
    if ($(this).text() == "Web1"){
        $("#main").html('<object data="http://www.myweb1.com"/>');
    }
    if ($(this).text() == "Web2"){
        $("#main").html('<object data="http://www.myweb2.com"/>');
    }
    if ($(this).text() == "Web3"){
        $("#main").html('<object data="http://www.myweb3.com"/>');
    }
    if ($(this).text() == "Web4"){
        $("#main").html('<object data="http://www.myweb3.com"/>');
    }

});
</script>
```

Also use `$(this)` that holds the `.menu` element that fired the listener.

Comment: Thank you very much, now jquery opens the web on the entire page of the navigator, not at "main" div. Maybe because It's doing an "a href" instead of click script.

Comment: That's because you need to put `e.preventDefault()` on the top of the function to not execute the default action for the `.menu` element (in this case, go to the page indicated in `href` attirubute). Check the answer again I have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

I created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mh87cppx/

Make sure to "return false" in your click handler otherwise the site might reload. Also as mentioned before $(this) needs to be utilized in your click handler to get a reference to the current element for your comparison.

```
$(document).on("click", ".menu", function(e) {
    if ($(this).text() == "Web1"){
        $("#main").html('"https://www.myweb1.com"');
    }
    if ($(this).text() == "Web2"){
        $("#main").html('"https://www.myweb2.com"');
    }
    if ($(this).text() == "Web3"){
        $("#main").html('"https://www.myweb3.com"');
    }
    if ($(this).text() == "Web4"){
        $("#main").html('"https://www.myweb4.com"');
    }
        return false;
});
```